# Docker resolução de nomes

Tags: docker, nginx

Estou configurando um proxy reverso com nginx + docker.

Tenho 02 máquinas que estão na rede bridge.

proxy :     172.17.0.2
app   :     172.17.0.3

Ambos containers estão configurados com nome

```
 server {
       listen 80;
       server_name portainer.domain;
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
          client_max_body_size 0;
      }
```

}

Com esta configuração ao acessar `http://portainer.domain` recebo erro 502 - Bad Gateway.

Quando eu altero para encaminhamento por IP, conforme abaixo funciona perfeitamente.

```
 server {
       listen 80;
       server_name portainer.domain;
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://172.17.0.3:9000;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
          client_max_body_size 0;
      }
```

Os dois containers estão na rede rede bridge default.

Se eu conectar no console de ambos containers eu consigo pingar por IP, porém não por nome do container.

Na máquina host também não consigo pingar por nome do container, somente por IP.

Já tentei também colocar `proxy_pass http://portainer:9000;`, onde portainer é o nome do container que eu desejo acessar e não obtive sucesso.

A máquina cliente está acessando o servidor de proxy reverso normalmente, o problema está na hora do servidor proxy encaminhar internamente a requisição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Você provavelmente só tem containers, em uma máquina.

2) Fazer qualquer amarração pelo IP do container não é sadio para a infraestrutura do docker.

3) Cada container possui seu próprio IP, diferente do ip do host. Portanto para cada um deles localhost é ele mesmo e não o host.

4) O IP do container varia a toda recriação e possivelmente até no restart.

5) Em uma rede bridge custom (quer dizer que não seja a default) a resolução de nomes acontece pelo nome do container, nome do serviço (no caso do swarm) ou pelo alias dado. Use essas informações para endereçar corretamente seu container alvo.

6) Gaste um tempinho estudando docker, de ponta-a-ponta. Teu erro é um mero problema de entendimento.